# How do I get an application id for Paypal?

Tags: paypal

I received API credentials but I need api application id to send Adaptive Accounts API Requests.

I used their sandbox app id: APP-80W284485P519543T.

now it's time to go live.

Comment: Great Questions. Documentation is kind of lame for this stuff. Happily, StackOverflow always has a great answer.

Comment: The Paypal documentation is some of the worst I've ever dealt with. Thanks for this question!

Comment: Design is changed & document not updated by paypal, every time hard to find details.  Thanks for this question!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In order to go live, you need to **[register your application with PayPal](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/goingLive/#register)** to obtain an application ID.

> When you submit your application to PayPal for review, the application
>   is quickly scanned for the requests to PayPal operations. If no
>   "advanced" operations are found, PayPal issues an AppID for the
>   production servers at the time you submit the application.

Comment: This link does not work. Page not found. I think this link is the new one: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/goingLive/

Comment: ah.. the terrible API and it's documentation that everybody is forced to use.

Comment: @Josh, the above helped a lot for me and i have developed adaptive payments for paypal with sandbox app id, but i am struggling to get live app id can you please look at my post here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48101484/how-do-i-get-app-id-for-adaptive-payments-paypal

Answer (score 3):

Just because PayPal docs are kind of messy like @Deekor said in the comments, I think it would be good to leave the following links in case anybody like me is wondering where the hell do you **REALLY get an AppID** (e.g.: for adaptive payments).

- Just go to **[PayPal Developer](https://developer.paypal.com/)**, once you log in, go to **Create and manage Classic API apps** or directly to **[PayPal Apps](https://www.paypal-apps.com/)**.
- Create an app, once created you get a **Sandbox ID** which is you **AppID** and the **LiveID** as pending.

Comment: hi any one can provide clear view how to generate appid and get secreate client id and all.how integrate paypal in android mobile application clearly please.

Answer (score 1):

Date: 3/28/16 (new developer.paypal.com Adaptive APPID walk-through)

Hi All - I will update this since it's been a while. **Please note this is for the classic Adaptive Payment APP ID (NVP/SOAP APIs)** process and **not** for the REST APP or BrainTree V.Zero SDK.

Do the following:

1. Go to developer.paypal.com
2. Log in with PayPal Account email and password
3. Click the 'Dashboard' tab up top
4. Click 'My APPs & Credentials'
   [image]
5. Click 'Create & Manage NVP/SOAP API apps link
   [image]
6. On the redirect to the *classic* developer portal, Login to PayPal account you want to apply for the APP ID with (a business PayPal account is highly suggestive for underwriting approval)
7. For *Live* APP IDs it takes between 24-48 hours; you *should* get notified when approved. If you don't, contact business support. The number is in your paypal account / contact us section (pending status)
8. For *SandBox* you'll get the APP ID right away, regardless of how you applied; live or sandbox
9. You should see the APP ID in the classic developer portal in the 'manage your apps' section. 
   [image]

For REST APP ID please [click here link](http://geekmechanics.weebly.com/paypal-rest)

Comment: paypal now gives me an error when i try to login to paypal-apps.com (classic developer portal)

Comment: hmm.. See what you mean. I tried with safari and chrome, logged into developer.paypal.com and accessed the url from that site and it failed as well. Sounds like there's an issue with that page. I would submit an inquiry here and ask them. Make sure to send a screen shot. Go here https://www.paypal-techsupport.com/app/home and click contact support @ the bottom. Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks, i'll come back here after I get a response from them and hopefully can update the answer again

Comment: Apperently things have changed, they no longer support creation of NVP/SOAP APIs. What to do ?

Comment: Hi Xsmaeil - they do support nvp/soap api's still, however the APPID can no longer be gathered in this fashion. If you want to create a partner commerce like marketplace than you'll want to look into the PayPal Commerce Platform. https://developer.paypal.com/docs/commerce-platform/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue today. I finally found my live app-id using this cURL:

> curl -v -X POST "https://api-m.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token"
> -u "CLIENT_ID:CLIENT_SECRET"
> -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
> -d "grant_type=client_credentials"

Ref: https://developer.paypal.com/api/rest/authentication/

Note that the url in the doc is "api-m.**sandbox**.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token". I removed the "sandbox" word in order to get the live appId.

Hope that helps!