# What are service address and App ID of paypal connector configuration in mulesoft?

Tags: mule, connector

How to get the service address and App ID of paypal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MuleSoft is a company, so they don't have any relationship to it. I'm assuming you are talking in the context of MuleSoft's [PayPal connector](https://docs.mulesoft.com/paypal-connector/0.3.7/#configuring-the-paypal-connector-global-element). Just reading the documentation it explains it:

- Service Address PayPal endpoint reference. Refer to this for [PayPal endpoints](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/endpoints/).
- App Id PayPal Application ID.

If you need help with the application ID, you can find a previous answer about [getting a PayPal application id](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9485509/721855).

Comment: I didn't understand this service endpoints. Could you please say about it...

Comment: any example of service address?

Comment: That's something defined by PayPal. Depending on what services of the API you are accessing you need to choose one of the endpoints. It is explained at https://developer.paypal.com/docs/nvp-soap-api/gs-PayPalAPIs/#endpoint. You need to be familiar with the PayPal API.